# How to alter your homepage in Oracle's enterprise manager

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-enterprise-manager

**How can I change my starting page after logging in to Oracle's enterprise manager?**

Everytime I log in to Oracle's Enterprise Manager (SOA 12c) to inspect the flow traces of my middleware projects I have to click through a couple of screens to get to my actual flow traces. You start in the home screen, from which I 95% of the time have to navigate through ../SOA/Soa-Infra/deployed_composites to get to where I'll do most of the monitoring.

I know the cloud products have a setting which allows you to change the starting page after logging in, but I haven't managed to find it for non-"cloud control" enterprise manager.

Do you know how to change this home setting? For I would love to set it to my Soa-Infra instead of the regular home, saving me some minutes every day navigating the same screens.

Cheers,

Jesper

Comment: Can;t you just bookmark the page you want to end up on?

Comment: That does work yes, so it solves my problem. I do wonder if it's possible in EM though.